# ActiveJDBC: save() generates insert only for auto-generated primary key?

Tags: java, postgresql, activejdbc

I recently started using ActiveJDBC.  I have the following table (postgresql)

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id                   uuid PRIMARY KEY,
    email                text UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    password             text,
    <some more nullable columns>
    created_at           timestamp with time zone NOT NULL default (now() at time zone 'utc'),
    updated_at           timestamp with time zone
);
```

As you can see, the primary key is of type uuid and has no auto-generate value of any kind.

This is my User class which models the table :

```
public class User extends Model
{
    public User() {
        setId(UUID.randomUUID());  // sets value to primary key
    }
...
}
```

This is my attempt to create a new row and insert it :

```
    User u = new User();
    System.out.println(u.saveIt());
```

actually, I expected the insert to fail, since I did not set any value for mandatory email column.  However, simply got false as return value. when I turned on logging, I saw that the framework generated an update sql instead of insert:

```
[main] INFO org.javalite.activejdbc.DB - Query: "UPDATE users SET email = ?, ..., updated_at = ? WHERE id = ?", with parameters: <null>, <null>, <null>, <null>, <null>, <null>, <null>, <2016-01-07 17:30:46.025>, <0621fbdb-5b95-4ee7-a474-8ee9165e2982>, took: 1 milliseconds
```

so I looked at the `save()` method inside `org.javalite.activejdbc.Model` class and saw this piece of code:

```
    if (getId() == null) {
        result = insert();
    } else {
        result = update();
    }
```

does this mean that id column has to be empty in order for an insert to be generated ? if this is true this is unacceptable, so I must be missing something.

Comment: update statement is not an issue if it's designed to save only persistent objects.

Comment: what do yo mean "only persistent objects"? only objects whch already exist in DB?  this is not what the documentation says

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@sharonbn, please, see this documentation page: http://javalite.io/surrogate_primary_keys. 
ActiveJDBC depends on autogenerated IDs. If the ID == null, the frameworks assumes this is a new record, and generates INSERT statement. If it is non-null, it is assumed the record already exists, and generates UPDATE.

In your case, you will need to explicitly call `user.insert()` instead of `user.saveIt()`.  This is an 'expert' mode in cases when developers want to be in control of ID management. Further, the method `user.update()` is private. So for you to insert a new record, you will be calling

`user.insert();`

and for updates:

`user.save();
// or:
user.saveIt();`

, depending on what you want.